# how to attach hyperlink on caption text post on facebook

Tags: android, facebook

Here is my code I'm using::, Here I'm able to post a photo name "icon" image with caption text. But I want to attach a hyper-link on the photo and a caption text so somebody on facebook site who is clicking on this photo or text. I used href, attachment and link keys, but nothing happens.

```
private void postPhoto_Message()
{
Bundle params = new Bundle();       
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BitmapDrawable bd =     (BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);    
Bitmap mutableBitmap = bd.getBitmap().copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
mutableBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] imgData = stream.toByteArray();  
params.putByteArray("photo",imgData);           
params.putString("caption", "My score is !");               
params.putString("href","http://www.zazzle.com/blackoakgames");        
params.putString("attachment", "{\"name\":\""+"seriesname"+"\","
+"\"href\":\""+"http://www.google.com\","+"\"description\":\""+"description"+"\"}");
params.putString("link", "http://www.blackoakgames.com/ck");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
new PhotoUploadListener(), null);    
}
```

Comment: Any luck with a solution since you asked this about a year ago?

Comment: may it be that hyperlinks are disabled for security reasons?